# Force IE Compatitbility Mode

Tags: 6

I need to force IE to show my site in compatibility mode, and I know I can just add a META header. The problem is how... can anyone point me in the right direction please? I'm running a custom theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE has a header for controlling this, [X-UA-Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Normally, people set this to 'IE=edge,chrome=1' which disables compatibility mode and tries to force [Google Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/).  If you want to [emulate IE7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can use 'EmulateIE7'.

In Drupal 7, it is best to use a [hook_html_head_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) for this

```
function MYTHEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  $head_elements['MYTHEME_ie_compatability'] = array(
    '#type' => 'html_tag',
    '#tag' => 'meta',
    '#attributes' => array(
    'name' => 'X-UA-Compatible',
    'content' => 'EmulateIE7',
    ),
  );

  $head_elements['MYTHEME_ie_compatability']['#attached']['drupal_add_http_header'][] = 
    array('X-UA-Compatible', $head_elements['MYTHEME_ie_compatability']['#attributes']['content']);
}
```

This sets the `<meta>` in the `<head>` and also sets an HTTP header in the response.

In Drupal 6, you could use

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_set_header('X-UA-Compatible: EmulateIE7');
}
```

You can also do this via Apache (eg, in .htaccess) with

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-UA-Compatible EmulateIE7
</IfModule>
```

Comment: They are using v6 so this would be incorrect. http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_set_header/6

Comment: Sorry I'm new to D6... Where exactly should I insert the D6 function? Thanks

Comment: You can put the function in the template.php for your theme.